# Iterating over linked list and adding new value

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, cs50

I am new to the topic of linked list and having a hard time figuring how to add a 'u' after every 'o' the user enters. Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated.

The programs input:

> ./queensenglish
>
> Input string?:
>
> i love the color yellow

The program's expected output:

> Charlatan!  I use the Queen’s English:
>
> i louve the coulour yellouw

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char myChar;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* stringToList(char* inputString)
{
    node* first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    first->myChar = 'a';
    first->next = NULL;
    node* current = first;

    char* s;
    for(s = inputString; *s != '\0'; s++)
    {
        node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        newNode->myChar = *s;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        current->next = newNode;
        current = newNode;
    }
    return first->next;
}

char* listToString(node* firstChar)
{
    // get the length of the string
    int totalLen = 0;
    node* current = firstChar;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        totalLen++;
        current = current->next;
    }

    char *newString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(totalLen+1));
    char *iter = newString;
    current = firstChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLen; i++)
    {
        *iter = current->myChar;
        current = current->next;
        iter++;
    }
    *iter = '\0';
    return newString;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Read in an input string
    printf("Input string?: \n");
    char* myString = GetString();

    // Convert that string into a linked list
    node* firstChar = stringToList(myString);

    node* current = firstChar;
    while(current != NULL){

        if(strcmp(&current->myChar, "o") == 0 || (strcmp(&current->myChar, "O") == 0)
        {
            //insert a 'u' after every 'o'
            //printf("Char: %c\n", current->myChar);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    // convert the list back into a string
    char* newString = listToString(firstChar);

    // print out the "corrected" string
    printf("Charlatan! I use the Queen's English:\n");
    printf("%s\n", newString);
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(&current->myChar, "o") == 0` it's UB --> `current->myChar == 'o'`

Comment: insertNode : { 'u', NULL}, nextNode : current->next, insertNode->next = nextNode; current->next = insertNode;

Comment: `node* first = malloc(sizeof(node)); first->myChar = 'a';first->next = NULL;...return first->next;` memory leak --> `node first; node* current = &first; ... return first.next;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for point out the UB to and for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(current->myChar == 'o' || current->myChar == 'O')
{
    node *insertNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    insertNode->myChar = 'u';
    insertNode->next = current->next;
    current->next = insertNode;
    current = current->next;//skip 'u' node
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, You are using `strcmp` to compare `char`s which is wrong. `strcmp` is used to compare two `string`s, *not* to compare two characters. You need to use the `==` operator to check if `current->myChar == 'o' || current->myChar == 'O'`

Next, every time you get a node whose `char` i.e. `myChar` is `'o'` or `'O'` you need to:

1. Create a new node with its `myChar` equal to `u`.
2. Make this new node point the node to which the 'o' or 'O' node was pointing.
3. Make the 'o' or 'O' node point to this new node.

So in you can do like this:

```
node* current = firstChar;
while(current != NULL){
         //insert a 'u' after every 'o'
         if(current->myChar == 'o' || current->myChar == 'O') {
                 // create a new node
                 struct node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                 if (tmp == NULL) {
                         /* malloc failed */
                         printf("Error: Malloc fail, cannot add 'u'\n");
                 } else { /* malloc succeded */
                         tmp->myChar = 'u';
                         tmp->next = current->next;
                         current->next = tmp;
                 }
         }
         current = current->next;
}
```